# How to restart meteor by systemd

Tags: meteor, systemd, systemctl

I need to use systemd to restart the meteor as a service, so I create cloud.service in `/etc/systemd/system/`. The file looks like below,

```
[Unit]
Description=cloud
After=network.target

[Service]
User=someone
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/someone/cloud/
ExecStart=/home/someone/cloud/start.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and in the `start.sh`, it looks like

```
nohup meteor &
```

But when the system restarts, the service cannot start.

```
● cloud.service - cloud
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/cloud.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Fri 2018-11-30 03:22:51 UTC; 13min ago

Nov 30 03:22:51 cloud-euro systemd[1]: cloud.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 30 03:22:51 cloud-euro systemd[1]: cloud.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 30 03:22:51 cloud-euro systemd[1]: cloud.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 30 03:22:51 cloud-euro systemd[1]: Stopped cloud.
Nov 30 03:22:51 cloud-euro systemd[1]: cloud.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 30 03:22:51 cloud-euro systemd[1]: Failed to start cloud.
Nov 30 03:22:51 cloud-euro systemd[1]: cloud.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 30 03:22:51 cloud-euro systemd[1]: cloud.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
```

I've tried to use `Type=forking`, but the situation doesn't change. Any suggestions?

Comment: what permission does the "someone" user have ?

Comment: Thanks for asking. based on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126797/command-to-know-privileges-of-a-user-group, I cannot say exactly what permission I have, but on linux I can use sudo to add files in /etc/systemd/system

Comment: Why not directly start your meteor from ExecStart in service file like 
'ExecStart=nohup meteor'

Looks like the script is exiting and since restart always is given, systemd is trying to restart the script continuously and hitting the limit.